# Areca Backup problem with Eclipse to start

Tags: linux, centos, backup, eclipse

I am trying to install Areca 7.5 on my CentOS 7 VM.
But when I try to launch the starting script I get the following error.

```
[root@localhost areca]# ./areca.sh 
java version "1.6.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.12) (rhel-1.13.12.5.el7_2-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.40-b40, mixed mode)
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.getDevice(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.common.ArecaImages.loadImage(ArecaImages.java:107)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.common.ArecaImages.<clinit>(ArecaImages.java:43)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:142)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.Launcher.launchImpl(Launcher.java:141)
    at com.myJava.system.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:47)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:48)
16-11-23 10:00 - ERROR - Unexpected error

16-11-23 10:00 - WARNING - Critical error during initialization ... exiting.org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]

    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)16-11-23 10:00 - INFO - Closing Areca (force=false)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
16-11-23 10:00 - INFO - Closing Areca (force=false) at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)16-11-23 10:00 - INFO - Closing Areca (force=false)

    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.getDevice(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.common.ArecaImages.loadImage(ArecaImages.java:107)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.common.ArecaImages.<clinit>(ArecaImages.java:43)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.Application.<clinit>(Application.java:142)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.Launcher.launchImpl(Launcher.java:141)
    at com.myJava.system.AbstractLauncher.launch(AbstractLauncher.java:47)
    at com.application.areca.launcher.gui.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:48)
```

Anyone knows how to solve?